# How to move UIPageViewController's PageController buttons position in the View

Tags: ios, swift, uipageviewcontroller

I have implemented Page Swipe with a UIPageViewController.

Delegates and DataSource are working properly. The indexing, the whole thing.

The problem I have is, since the Page Controller is part of the UIPageViewController, its default position is at the bottom. Since it is part of it, I can not change it on the storyboard.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

I tried this, but didn't work

```
   self.view.frame = CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 30.0), size: CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.size.height - 200.0))
```

Also tried this.
But all it did was create a second PageControl

```
    let pageControl = UIPageControl()
pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.grayColor()
pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
pageControl.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()
pageControl.numberOfPages = 4
pageControl.center = self.view.center
self.view.addSubview(pageControl)

pageControl.layer.position.y = self.view.frame.height - 200; 
// 200 point from bottom of the screen
```

I have googled it, but didn't find anything useful.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible solutions:

1. Update current UIPageControl's position in UIPageViewController's viewDidLayoutSubviews like it's shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36573084/11488484)
2. [Create](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32836995/11488484) your own UIPageControl and do not use the default one

Personally, I don't like hacking system controls, so I'd prefer to create a new one and customize it as I want. 
Good luck!

Comment: So you're saying to create a new one? Option 2? Is there a reason I should not hack it?

Comment: I tried that example, but I don't know where the solution provider is getting the .pageIndex from. on the line that has         pageControl.currentPage = pageContentView?.pageIndex
.Do you happen to know?